# Keyboard height on Android

Tags: android, android-softkeyboard, android-windowmanager, android-viewtreeobserver

I'm getting the keyboard's height on Android by implementing a ViewTreeObserver.OnGlobalLayoutListener by doing:

```
final Rect r = new Rect();
mRootLayout.getWindowVisibleDisplayFrame(r);
int screenHeight = mRootLayout.getRootView().getHeight();
final int keyboardHeight = screenHeight - (r.bottom);
```

My problem is that on some devices I'm getting the keyboard height as twice the status bar height. What is going on?  How could I solve that issue?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

```
this.getWindow().setSoftInputMode(
            WindowManager.LayoutParams.SOFT_INPUT_ADJUST_PAN);
```

If you add this code, it will adjust your screen automatically when the keyboard pops out.
However, the adjustment will occur by PUSHING your layout up. Which means, if your layout does not have a scrollBar, some view will be cut unless until keyboard does not pop down again.

PS: you can add the same code in your apps manifest file of same activity.

```
<activity android:name="YOUR ACTIVITY"
        android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustPan"/>
```

All possible combination of windoSoftInputMode

```
android:windowSoftInputMode=["stateUnspecified",
                                   "stateUnchanged", "stateHidden",
                                   "stateAlwaysHidden", "stateVisible",
                                   "stateAlwaysVisible", "adjustUnspecified",
                                   "adjustResize", "adjustPan"]
```

Link: [Activity Element, Android's documentation](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/activity-element.html)

Hope it helps! Cheers!

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer. I need that the activity has adjustResize instead of adjustPan, otherwise some views that shouldn't be cut would be cut.